how to determine the distance between metallic electrodes and channel materials at the interface?
We need attach the electrodes to channel materials (no matter the channel materials is 0D,1D ,2D or 3D),while we have to determine the distance between metallic electrodes and channel materials at the interface. How could we do it?
I am asking this question because the distance at the interface is tightly related with potential distribution (charge distribution and poisson eqution) at the interface.

After reading the manual of siesta-5.0.0, I noticed the following words:

TS.Forces true (logical) Control whether the forces are calculated. If not
TranSIESTA will use slightly less memory and the performance slightly
increased, however the final forces shown are incorrect.
If this is true the file SystemLabel.TSFA (and possibly the
SystemLabel.TSFAC) will be cre- ated. They contain forces for the atoms
that are having updated density-matrix elements (TS.Elec.<>.DM-update
all).
Generally one should not expect good forces close to the electrode/device
interface since this typically has some electrostatic effects that are
inherent to the TranSIESTA method. Forces on atoms far from the electrode
can safely be analyzed.

And I did not find transiesta options to relax the structure in the manual of siesta-5.0.0.
In summary, I think this is the official confirmation we cannot optimize the distance between electrodes and devices at the interface with transiesta. And this step should be done in the siesta calculations,just like we usually do to determine the distance between heterstrutures.
